# Como alterar uma imagem em runtime com o WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Tenho um item que deve alterar as imagens conforme uma verificação de valor antigo e valor novo vão acontecendo. Tenho uma parte dos códigos pronta e as imagens de static resources. Mas, estou bloqueada em relação de como proceder a partir daqui

Tenho este código que indica a diferença de valores.

```
public enum Deviation
        {
            None = 0,
            Up = 1,
            Down = 2
        }

 public bool ShowDifference { get; set; }

 public double ShouldShowDifference
            {
                get => // colocar a chamada de verificação e determinação de imagem com o metodo de ValorAlterado

                set => _showDifference = value;
            }
public Deviation ValorAlterado
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Value == ValorAnterior)
                        return Deviation.None;

                    return Value > ValorAnterior? Deviation.Up : Deviation.Down;
                }
            }

            double ValorAnterior{ get; set; } = double.NaN;

            public double Value
            {
                get => _value;
                set
                {
                    this.ValorAnterior = _value;
                    _value = value;
                }
            }
```

E preciso que esta indicação vá para este xaml, lmebrando que para a condição de deviation com o UP o static resource deve ser o Icons.Buttons.Up e para o DOWN deve ser Icons.Buttons.Down

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource Icons.Buttons.Down}" Height="20"  Width="20"/>
```

Estou desenvolvendo ainda como formar os bindings e afins, então estou um pouco perdida em como juntar estas partes que desenvolvi com o objetivo geral.

---------- UPDATE APOS RESPOSTA DO BRUNO

Código que fiz, ao debugar funciona corretamente, o problema agora é só a imagem aparecer corretamente.

```
public Image DeviationImage
            {
                get
                {
                    if (ShowDifference)
                    {
                        switch ((double)ValueIncreased)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                return (Image)Application.Current.Resources["ArrowUp"];

                            case 2:
                                return (Image)Application.Current.Resources["ArrowDown"];
                            case 0:
                                return (Image)Application.Current.Resources["ArrowEqual"];
                        }    
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

XAML - Onde vou colocar a imagem

```
<Image Source="{Binding DeviationImage}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
```

XAML - Resources no xaml

```
        <Image x:Key="ArrowUp" Source="{telerik:RadGlyph Glyph='&#xe017;', Foreground='Blue'}"/>
        <Image x:Key="ArrowDown" Source="{telerik:RadGlyph Glyph='&#xe019;', Foreground='Blue'}"/>
        <Image x:Key="ArrowEqual" Source="{telerik:RadGlyph Glyph='&#xe121;', Foreground='Blue'}"/>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fica aqui um exemplo de como mudar uma imagem em tempo de execução:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!field.Equals(value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public class ImageModel : Model
{
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private static Random r = new Random();
    public ImageModel() {
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            var assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            string btn = r.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? "up.png" : "down.jpg";
            Uri oUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + assemblyName + ";component/" + btn, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            ImageBtn = new BitmapImage(oUri);
            ImageBtn.Freeze();
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageBtn");
        });
    }

    public BitmapImage ImageBtn {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

E o XML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ImageModel></local:ImageModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageBtn}" Height="200"  Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Agradeço imensamente pela ajuda! Você poderia me dizer, como retorno minha imagem? ela é um static resource Icons.Buttons.Down e Icons.Buttons.Up

Comment: Fiz um update na pergunta com os novos codigos

Comment: @OlivF Atualizei a resposta. Deve estar mais claro agora. Até porque a minha resposta anterior estava um bocado longe da resposta certa.

Comment: Muito Obrigada Bruno, sua resposta me ajudou bastante. Consegui, mudei alguns pontos usando um converter.